# Show where added links in edits lead

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

On the [suggested edits page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits), there will occasionally be somebody who adds or updates a link.

If most of the reviewers are like me, they're too lazy to actually hover over the link and just think "cool, they're fixing link rot and adding links to relevant documentation" and just approve it without actually seeing where the links go.

This can be abused easily. I'm willing to bet a small fortune that it would be easy to get edits that add [irrelevant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bavarian_cuisine) or [spam](http://example.org/Kittens/) links through edit approval.

To prevent this, when a link is added or edited, **the url should appear in the edit summary**.

Comment: If you're too lazy to actually check the links, then maybe you shouldn't be approving those edits. I *always* check the links.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't necessary because you can already switch between the rendered output diff and the Markdown source diff, which shows things like changed URLs or inserted comments.

[image: Markdown diff button]

> If most of the reviewers are like me, they're too lazy to actually hover over the link and just think "cool, they're fixing link rot and adding links to relevant documentation" and just approve it without actually seeing where the links go.

Well… don't do that.

Comment: That takes as much effort as hovering over the links; the point is to prevent any obstacles from seeing where the links go.

Comment: @PeterOlson You only have to click it once, your preference is saved.